# I'm getting an absolute path in $_SERVER['PHP_SELF ']

Tags: php, symfony, nginx, nginx-config

I'm struggling with Nginx. Currently we are migrating a legacy platform into Symfony and it's working great so far. The approach is to register all the legacy PHP's as routes and load them in a custom controller (there was not a front controller).

It's working great, I've struggled a lot to get an Nginx configuration which would work (I need to get routes endind in `.php` redirected to `public/index.php` as valid routes to get them matched with the registered ones).

This is what I've got so far (mostly copy/paste, reading docs, and trial/error):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name localhost;

    root /var/www/html/public;
    index index.php;

    location = /favicon.ico { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { access_log off; log_not_found off; }

    location / {
        # try to serve file directly, fallback to index.php
        try_files $uri /static$uri /index.php$is_args$args;

        # try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
        set $redirect_url $uri;
    }

    # optionally disable falling back to PHP script for the asset directories;
    # nginx will return a 404 error when files are not found instead of passing the
    # request to Symfony (improves performance but Symfony's 404 page is not displayed)
    # location /bundles {
    #     try_files $uri =404;
    # }
    
    location ~* "\.php$" {
        fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;
        include fastcgi_params;

        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        fastcgi_param PATH_TRANSLATED /var/www/html/public/index.php;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_URI $document_uri;
        fastcgi_param REDIRECT_URL $redirect_url;
        fastcgi_param DOCUMENT_ROOT $realpath_root;

        fastcgi_split_path_info ^/(/.*)(/.*)$;


        # fastcgi_intercept_errors off;
        fastcgi_buffering off;
        fastcgi_connect_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_send_timeout 300s;
        fastcgi_read_timeout 600s;

        # fastcgi_buffers 16 16k;
        # fastcgi_buffer_size 32k;
    }

    error_log  /var/log/nginx/error.log;
    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
}
```

The problem I'm getting right now is that `$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']` is getting filled right now with the server's absolute path instead of relative to the root of the website, as usually. for example, I'm getting `/var/www/html/public/foo/bar.php` instead of `/foo/bar.php`.

I would just remove that variable from the legacy project, but it seems that there are some libraries depending on that variable too. Also, it feels dirty to screw that variables with non-standard values.

Anybody has a clue about why is this happening?

Edited: My `fastcgi_params` included file:

```
fastcgi_param  QUERY_STRING       $query_string;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_METHOD     $request_method;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_TYPE       $content_type;
fastcgi_param  CONTENT_LENGTH     $content_length;

fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_NAME        $fastcgi_script_name;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_URI        $request_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_URI       $document_uri;
fastcgi_param  DOCUMENT_ROOT      $document_root;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PROTOCOL    $server_protocol;
fastcgi_param  REQUEST_SCHEME     $scheme;
fastcgi_param  HTTPS              $https if_not_empty;

fastcgi_param  GATEWAY_INTERFACE  CGI/1.1;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_SOFTWARE    nginx/$nginx_version;

fastcgi_param  REMOTE_ADDR        $remote_addr;
fastcgi_param  REMOTE_PORT        $remote_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_ADDR        $server_addr;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_PORT        $server_port;
fastcgi_param  SERVER_NAME        $server_name;

# PHP only, required if PHP was built with --enable-force-cgi-redirect
fastcgi_param  REDIRECT_STATUS    200;
```

Comment: Could you provide file content of `fastcgi_params` file, which included by `include fastcgi_params;` line. Usually it located near the nginx config, please?

Comment: @FallDi Question edited!